# why there no is cos and sin sign there in equation?

Tags: trigonometry

[Please have a look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PfyJ.png)

I think here this Identity is used

$cos(a-b)=cos(a)cos(b)+sin(a)sin(b)$

but why there no cos and sin sign with highlighted terms ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is correct. 
The have assumed a right angled triangle with side lengths P and Q and angle enclosed between hypotenuse and side P as $ \phi $

Obviously, let hypotenuse = R
$$ R = \sqrt{P^2+Q^2} $$

therefore $$ P/R = cos\phi $$

$$ Q/R = sin\phi $$

Rest you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos (\Omega t+\Phi)$$

$$\cos \left(\text{$\Omega $t}-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q}{P}\right)\right)$$

$$\sin (\text{$\Omega $t}) \sin \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q}{P}\right)\right)+\cos (\text{$\Omega $t}) \cos \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q}{P}\right)\right)$$

$$\frac{Q \sin (\text{$\Omega $t})}{P \sqrt{\frac{Q^2}{P^2}+1}}+\frac{\cos (\text{$\Omega $t})}{\sqrt{\frac{Q^2}{P^2}+1}}$$

$$\frac{Q \sin (\Omega t)}{P \sqrt{\frac{Q^2}{P^2}+1}}+\frac{P \cos (\Omega t)}{P \sqrt{\frac{Q^2}{P^2}+1}}$$

$$\frac{Q \sin (\Omega t)}{\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}}+\frac{P \cos (\Omega t)}{\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}}$$

$$\sqrt{P^2+Q^2} \left(\frac{Q \sin (\Omega t)}{\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}}+\frac{P \cos (\Omega t)}{\sqrt{P^2+Q^2}}\right)$$

$$P \cos (\text{$\Omega $t})+Q \sin (\text{$\Omega $t})$$

Hope this helps